# Need procedure to integrate a wrapbootstrap theme into a nodejs Expressjs app

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I got this template:

https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/base-admin-WB00U99JJ

Base Admin 3.0 that i have purchased.

I want to integrate it into a nodejs/expressjs app.

Im running into difficulties, mainly that:

1. Jade seems to always install
2. I got a views and public folders, which I dont know which one to use properly.

Any specific instructions on how to integrate such twitter bootstrap template into a node js app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. put all the .js files for the theme under public/javascripts
2. put all the .css for the theme files under public/stylesheets
3. include your .js files and .css files in your views/layout.jade
4. start developing the front page of your app in views/index.jade

(see jade documentation for how to include scripts and stylesheets)

If you'd rather not use jade and just have the server return an html file that includes both header and body, you can change to

```
res.render(index...
```

in your "/" route in app.js to

```
res.sendfile('path/to/htmlfile');
```